# How to get SQS messages that have already been processed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, queue, amazon-sqs

I have a common problem I think: I need to persist all the messages from a queue, even if they've already been processed and moved off from the queue.

I'm using SQS as queue system, and my first solution for that problem was persist every message that are sent to SQS in DynamoDB.

But I did a local test using Redis as queue system and I found out that it resolves that problem, saving some 'metadata' from each message that is sent to the queue. Example:

- A message with ID = 'asdas-q1223-dasdacc-3222dd' is sent to the queue
- It is processed by a random service
- It is moved off from the queue
- after that, I can perform a action like this to get a data from a specific message that has moved off from the queue:

  ```
  getJob(jobId: string)
  ```

I just need the same behavior for SQS. Is there the same behavior as Redis in SQS?

Answer (score 2):

Once a message has been deleted from an Amazon SQS queue, **it is no longer available**. This includes any metadata associated with the message.

If you wish to **save the message**, or information about the message, you would need to do it while processing the message (before processing has finished).

However, an alternative approach would be to send the messages to an Amazon SNS topic. Then, you could **subscribe two Amazon SQS queues to the Amazon SNS topic**. One queue would be used in the normal existing way. The other queue could be used to 'save' the message. For example, the Amazon SQS queue could trigger an AWS Lambda function and that function could store the message somewhere (eg in a database or in an Amazon S3 object). It won't have details about how the message was processed in the 'existing' queue, but it will have a copy of the message. It will, however, be a 'separate' message, so it will have a different Message ID.